# Not able to access hard disk on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

I am having a weird issue. I am using an HP pavilion dv6 laptop. It has windows 8 as well as ubuntu on the same disk (without partition). I do use both the OSs. When I boot on Ubuntu and try to access the hard disk I get this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/abhi/36984CC960784648: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda1" "/media/abhi/36984CC960784648"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I did disable hibernation as well on Windows and even when I shut down Windows and boot up Ubuntu I still get this error. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you also disable fast startup?

Comment: No I havent. I will try that.

Comment: Or just mount it read only?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable Windows fast start-up option.

Open Control Panel -> Energy Settings and select Change what the power buttons do.

Choose Change settings that are currently unavailable, scroll down and uncheck
Turn on fast start-up (recommended).

Restart the computer and you won't have this error anymore.